# MySQL 単一テーブル内でのレコードのコピーについて

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQLで、一つのテーブル内でレコードをコピーしようと思います。
「一つのレコードの複製を複数行作成する」操作を１回の操作で実行することは可能でしょうか？
複数行挿入する場合は、「INSERT INTO VALUES(...),(...)」で実行できます。
単純に複製する場合は、「INSERT～SELECT」を使うことでできます。
しかし、「一つのレコードの複製を複数行挿入する方法」がわかりません。
一度コピー元のデータを読み込んでから、「INSERT INTO VALUES(...),(...)」を実行するか、「INSERT～SELECT」を複数回実行するかしかないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。
Mysql　Ver.5.0.51a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT は UNION で複数繋ぐことができるので、これを指定すればいいと思います。

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

Comment: 質問は”1つのレコードの複製”のため、重複を除去する UNION ではなく UNION ALL が正しいと思われます。

Comment: そうですね。ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Answer (score 0):

少し強引ですが、適当なテーブルと結合して複製するのはどうでしょうか？
今後も使う場合は、適当なテーブルの部分は、
ダミーのレコードを返すストアドを作成してもいいかもです。

```
INSERT
    INTO
        コピー先テーブル(
            col1
            ,col2
        )
        SELECT
              copy_tbl.col1
              ,copy_tbl.col2
          FROM
              コピー先テーブル copy_tbl
              LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        col1
                    FROM
                        適当なテーブル 
                    LIMIT 繰り返し件数
                  ) dummy_tbl
              ON 1 = 1;
```